# Production install cake 2.0 in mediatemple/plesk

Tags: cakephp, installation, cakephp-2.0, plesk, mediatemple

I'm currently trying to install cake on a new site hosted on mediatemple/plesk on a shared ip. I have added the unzipped cake package to the httpdocs folder (../httpdocs/cake/), which is the server default for the site, as instructed in the cake documentation. It did not however bring me to the cake installation page, so as instructed in the cake documentation i reset the DocumentRoot for the site. The solution for document root that i found online for plesk was to set document root in  vhost.conf and vhost_ssl.conf in the conf folder for the site i wanted to redirect. each of these files now has the following line of code (only code in the document):

DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/(mydomain.com)/httpdocs/cake/app/webroot/

As it still does not load to the cake homepage/installation page (instead i get the apache test page...) i have continued to search online and in these forums, but just keep coming up with reiterations of creating the vhost.conf and vhost_ssl.conf files as i did above (same line of code and everything)

manually directing my browser through the filepath to cake/app/webroot/ and cake/app/webroot/index.php returns only a blank page.

Is there any other way to get this to direct to the installation page correctly so that i can start to build?

Answer (score 0):

DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/(mydomain.com)/httpdocs/cake/app/webroot/

i'd say this will not work.

Your index.php you'll need to access for cake is in "/var/www/vhosts/(mydomain.com)/httpdocs/cake/" if i'm correct.

You should *remove the DocumentRoot* and then browse to: **mydomain.com/cake/index.php**
there you should see the cake page

(this should be working before you try to set your DocumentRoot somewhere else)

Comment: I'm following the instructions listed here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/_downloads/en/CakePHPCookbook.pdf

The installation screen finally came up. Just took about 24 hours to do so, and a few more re-saves to the vhost.conf and vhost_ssl.conf files to get rid of the code my erver kept adding to them.